# Possibility of "ghost functions" with canvas requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, canvas

I was working with requestAnimationFrame(), and I thought,

say I had a function

```
function draw(){
  ...
  ...
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

now lets say I called `draw()` twice,

```
draw();
draw();
```

does this mean 2 different loops will be flowing async together ?, 
can this cause RAM overloading or similar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame(callback)` pushes callback in a stack of animation frames that will all get executed (fifo) at the same time, during the next *painting* event loop iteration.
So yes, you will have two different loops running, but not really async.
For the RAM a function is not a problem, however what you do in draw will be done twice in a raw and that's rarely what you want.
But having two **different** animation loops is a normal use case.